# Resolve conditionals in style file

Tags: conditionals, styles

I'm writing a style with latex `mypackage.sty`; in the `myfile.tex`:

```
\usepackage[option1]{mypackage}
```

where option may be: option2, option3,...

In `mypackage.sty`:

```
\DeclareOption{option1}{some code}
\DeclareOption{option2}{some code}
...
```

I know that I must declare a variable for each options and write a conditional sentence like:

```
\if option1 then
 \ExecuteOption{option1}
\elseif option2 then
 \ExecuteOption{option2}
...
\fi
\ProcessOptions\relax
```

of course isn't the correct syntax for the conditionals in latex. I'm trying to solve this, but I'm confused about to declare in correct way the variables `\ifoption1`, `\ifoption2`, ... and define the conditional sentence.

I would appreciate your help and guidance to solve this question.

Thanks in advance.

Gustavo

Comment: Usually, after the `\DeclareOption`s, one calls `\ProcessOptions`. This will execute the code of the options that have been provided in the `\usepackage` command.

Comment: Thanks @gernot I know this is the way to execute the options, my problem is write the sentence that identifies the option selected from other, and then execute these. I'm thinking create a specifics packages and use them. when needed.

Comment: I think I still don't understand what you want to achieve. If you write your own package that has `option1` and `option2`, then `\DeclareOption{option1}{code for option1}\DeclareOption{option2}{code for option2}\ProcessOptions` will have the effect that `code for option1` is executed if `option1` was given, and code for option2` is executed if `option2` was given. This is what the macro `\ProcessOptions` does. So what is the purpose of your `\if ... \elsif ... \else .. \fi`? It looks like a description of what `\ProcessOptions` does anyway.